# Selenium WebDriver: unable to locate element (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paypal

I'm trying to automate Paypal withdrawals by using C# and Selenium. The application logs into Paypal using provided credentials and clicks on the 'transfer money' link, which then shows a pop-up (which looks to be an iframe). My problem is that I can't click on any of the elements in the pop-up, and I've tried every suggestion I could find.

Here is a screenshot of the form and the underlying html:

[paypal form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7BE1.png)

I'm trying to click on the 'From' dropdown and among other things I've tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"selection-container\"]/form/section/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[1]/div[1]")).Click();
```

and

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].hidden = false;", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"selection-container\"]/form/section/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[1]/div[1]")));
```

but either get and 'Unable to locate element' or 'Element not visible' errors. How do I get to the 'From' input element on the pop-up? (If you're using paypal, you could also log in and take a peek at the pop-up if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to the `iframe` first

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")); // locate the iframe element
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"selection-container\"]/form/section/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[1]/div[1]")).Click();
```

And to switch back

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Comment: Always try to provide best answer, if OP could simply find element using `By.cssSelector` as `By.CssSelector("div#selection-container div.source-dropdown")` why are you suggesting to find it using `xpath`...??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div[class$='source-dropdown']")]
public IWebElement _ddSource;
```

The `'$'` specifies the end of the attribute, in the case the end of the class is `source-dropdown`

Comment: Or if you want to do it inline `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class$='source-dropdown']")).Click();`

Comment: Just tried it, still getting 'Unable to locate element'.

Comment: @Mario try using `By.CssSelector("div#selection-container div.source-dropdown")` after switching frame..

Answer (score 0):

at first you need to switch to that iframe. use the below code:

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[src ='/moneytransfer']");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
```

now you can click on that pop up by using this cssSelector:

```
div[class$='source-dropdown']
```

Comment: I tried this but still got the 'Unable to locate element' error. For some reason the iframe wasn't found. But if I looked using By.TagName instead as Guy suggested then it worked like a charm.